# How to Apply Styling Dynamic Created DOM in Objects jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I created two objects in jQuery ... and data in both objects is DOM elements that are created dynamically. I want to style those elements separately.  How can it be possible?

Here is the code:

```
var obj1 = {
    name : $("<p>Orange</p>"),
    price: $("<p class='price'>20</p>"),
    details : $("<div class='details'><p class='code'>1000</p><p class='pid'>234</p></div>"),
    details2 : $("<div class='details2'><p class='code2'>100</p><p class='pid2'>2334</p></div>")
}

var obj2 = {
    name : $("<p class='name'>Clone</p>"),
    price: $("<p class='price'>30</p>"),
    details : $("<div class='details'><p class='code'>1010</p><p class='pid'>345</p></div>")
}

jQuery.each(obj1, function(i, val) {
    $("#temp").append(i + " => " + val.text() + "<br/>");
})
```

Comment: Try a separate css class

Comment: I did but not working

Comment: Currently you are iterating only `obj1`, right ? You need both objects on the DOM ?

Comment: Make the property values HTML strings rather than jQuery objects (if you're not using the jQuery functionality elsewhere), and just use `val` instead of `val.text()`.

Comment: @SafinaSiddique does my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code is extracting the *text* of your jQuery elements, and so losing the HTML elements, classes, etc:

```
// Works, but you only get text, not HTML nodes, classes, etc,
// eg just 'Orange' from the first element of your object
$("#temp").append(i + " => " + val.text() + "<br/>");
```

Probably you tried just appending the actual jQuery object, and that did not work either, because `.append()` does not accept a mix of text, jQuery objects, and HTML:

```
// Does not work
$("#temp").append(i + " => " + val + "<br/>");
```

Instead, you can just append your jQuery object:

```
$("#temp").append(val);
```

Or if you want your object key info as well, you can append that first, and then append the jQuery object separately:

```
$("#temp").append(i + ' => ').append(val);
```

Or prepend your string key info to the jQuery object first, and then append the new result to the DOM:

```
val.prepend(i + ' => ');
$("#temp").append(val);
```

Here's a working snippet demonstrating this, with some styling to show the elements and classes are really included.  Click Run to see it in action.

```js
var obj1 = {
    name : $("<p>Orange</p>"),
    price: $("<p class='price'>20</p>"),
    details : $("<div class='details'><p class='code'>1000</p><p class='pid'>234</p></div>"),
    details2 : $("<div class='details2'><p class='code2'>100</p><p class='pid2'>2334</p></div>")
}

var obj2 = {
    name : $("<p class='name'>Clone</p>"),
    price: $("<p class='price'>30</p>"),
    details : $("<div class='details'><p class='code'>1010</p><p class='pid'>345</p></div>")
}

jQuery.each(obj1, function(i, val) {
    val.prepend(i + ' => ');
    $("#temp").append(val);
})
```

```css
.price { color: red; }
.code, .code2 { color: blue; }
.pid, .pid2 { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="temp"></div>
```